How to animate visibility of Compose Row with horizontal scroll?
I hava Row with  .horizontalScroll(scrollState) and I need to implement show and hide Row items animation.
I need it so that when it is necessary to hide elements, they all collapse into one element and smoothly disappear, and when it is necessary to show them, they grow from the first element into a full-fledged horizontal list.
I tried to do this with the help of AnimatedVisibility:
val delay = index * 100

AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = visible,
    enter = slideInHorizontally(
        initialOffsetX = { fullWidth -> -fullWidth / 2 }
    ) + fadeIn(
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300, delayMillis = delay)
    ) + scaleIn(
        initialScale = 0.8f,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300, delayMillis = delay)
    ),
    exit = fadeOut(
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 200)
    ) + shrinkHorizontally(
        targetWidth = { it / 2 } 
    )
) {
    // ...
}

But it doesn't work as I want.
Expected result as animated with CSS:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sequential Collapse and Expand</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }

        .list-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            position: relative;
            gap: 10px;
        }

        .list-item {
            background-color: #3498db;
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 40px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 40px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            transform-origin: left center;
            transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }

        /* Состояние "по умолчанию" */
        .list-container:not(:hover) .list-item {
            transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
            opacity: 1;
        }

        /* Состояние при наведении */
        .list-container:hover .list-item {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        /* Последовательное схлопывание */
        .list-container:hover .list-item:nth-child(5) {
            transform: translateX(-400px) scaleX(0);
            transition-delay: 0s;
        }

        .list-container:hover .list-item:nth-child(4) {
            transform: translateX(-300px) scaleX(0);
            transition-delay: 0.1s;
        }

        .list-container:hover .list-item:nth-child(3) {
            transform: translateX(-200px) scaleX(0);
            transition-delay: 0.2s;
        }

        .list-container:hover .list-item:nth-child(2) {
            transform: translateX(-100px) scaleX(0);
            transition-delay: 0.3s;
        }

        .list-container:hover .list-item:nth-child(1) {
            transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
            opacity: 0;
            transition-delay: 0.4s;
        }

        /* Последовательное раскрытие */
        .list-container:not(:hover) .list-item:nth-child(1) {
            transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
            transition-delay: 0.4s;
        }

        .list-container:not(:hover) .list-item:nth-child(2) {
            transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
            transition-delay: 0.3s;
        }

        .list-container:not(:hover) .list-item:nth-child(3) {
            transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
            transition-delay: 0.2s;
        }

        .list-container:not(:hover) .list-item:nth-child(4) {
            transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
            transition-delay: 0.1s;
        }

        .list-container:not(:hover) .list-item:nth-child(5) {
            transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
            transition-delay: 0s;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="list-container">
        <div class="list-item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="list-item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="list-item">Item 3</div>
        <div class="list-item">Item 4</div>
        <div class="list-item">Item 5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Do you have gifs for what you have and what you wish it to be?

@Thracian, I added a link where you can see the expected result

I'm not quite sure if I understood you correct, but my suggestion would be to use AnimatedContent between the collapsed item and the row. Maybe something like this:
// Horizontalscroll on top level container
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.horizontalScroll(scrollState)
) {
    FixedItem1()

    FixedItem2()

    AnimatedContent(visible) { visible ->
        if (visible) {
            CollapsedItem()
        } else {
            Row {
                CollapsibleItem3()

                CollapsibleItem4()
            }
        }
    }

    FixedItem5()
}

I'm on my phone so I can't reliably give suggestions for the transitionSpec, you could play with some different effects (if you want a growing effect a sliding animations depending on the target state might make sense). If I remember correctly, a SizeTransform is applied by default on AnimatedContent so the fixed items behind the collapsible section should automatically be animated, too without using schrinking and expanding transitions.
If you don't need fixed items just remove them and if you want so, you can change the top level Row to Box.
